# htons() function in socket programing

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I am new to socket programming and I am  trying to understand the operation of `htons()`. I've read a few tutorials on the Internet like [this](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/network_byte_orders.htm) one for instance. But I couldn't understand what `htons()` does exactly. I tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int  n;

    /* First call to socket() function */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Initialize socket structure */
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5001;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                          sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
         perror("ERROR on binding");
         exit(1);
    }

    /* Now start listening for the clients, here process will
    * go in sleep mode and will wait for the incoming connection
    */
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    /* Accept actual connection from the client */
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, 
                                &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR on accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* If connection is established then start communicating */
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read( newsockfd,buffer,255 );
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR reading from socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);

    /* Write a response to the client */
    n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR writing to socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The value of `sin_port` was shown as `35091` while debugging and I don't understand how `portno` changed from `5001` to `35091`. Could someone explain the reason for that change in value please?

Comment: What is your understanding of what `htons()` does?  Have you read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness.

Comment: According Linux manual The `htons()` function converts the unsigned short integer hostshort from host byte order to network byte order.

Comment: I know big Endianne and little Endianne but i dont know the operation of htons() exactly!!!

Comment: what happens if you change type of `portno` to `uint16_t`?

Comment: The `INADDR_*` constants are local byte order and also must be swapped to network order using `htonl` (not `htons`), as in `htonl(INADDR_ANY)`. You're only getting away without this because `INADDR_ANY` happens to be zero, which byte swaps to zero. If you used `INADDR_LOOPBACK`, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 155):

It has to do with the order in which bytes are stored in memory. The decimal number `5001` is  `0x1389` in hexadecimal, so the bytes involved are `0x13` and `0x89`. Many devices store numbers in *little-endian* format, meaning that the least significant byte comes first. So in this particular example it means that in memory the number `5001` will be stored as

```
0x89 0x13
```

The `htons()` function makes sure that numbers are stored in memory in network byte order, which is with the most significant byte first. It will therefore swap the bytes making up the number so that in memory the bytes will be stored in the order

```
0x13 0x89
```

On a *little-endian* machine, the number with the swapped bytes is `0x8913` in hexadecimal, which is `35091` in decimal notation. Note that if you were working on a *big-endian* machine, the `htons()` function would not need to do any swapping since the number would already be stored in the right way in memory.

The underlying reason for all this swapping has to do with the network protocols in use, which require the transmitted packets to use network byte order.

Answer (score 55):

`htons` is `host-to-network short`

This means it works on 16-bit short integers. i.e. 2 bytes.

This function swaps the endianness of a short.

Your number starts out at:

`0001 0011 1000 1001 = 5001`

When the endianness is changed, it swaps the two bytes:

`1000 1001 0001 0011 = 35091`

Comment: do you mean that 0001 0011 are host bytes and 1000 1001 are network byes?

Comment: @User123422 nope, you've got it wrong. Even-though binary form of 5001 is  "'0001 0011' '1000 1001'", when storing it in a LittleEndian machine it stores bytes in the opposite order ("'1000 1001' '0001 0011'"). Think about this; if 'A' and 'B' represents eight bits each, the binary number 'AB' will be stored as 'BA' in a LittleEndian machine (google 'Endianness' if you need to know why). 'htons()' is a convenient function that is used to convert any given short into BigEndian format ('AB' format), as that is the 'Network Byte Order'.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcaiHcBvDR4 In the last part of this video the guy explains the htons function.

Answer (score 7):

the `htons()` function converts values between host and network byte orders. There is a difference between *big-endian* and *little-endian* and network byte order depending on your machine and network protocol in use.

Answer (score 7):

It is done to maintain the arrangement of bytes which is sent in the network (endianness).

Depending upon the architecture of your device, data can be arranged in the memory either in the big endian format or little endian format. In networking, we call the representation of byte order as network byte order and in our host, it is called host byte order. All network byte order is in big endian format.

If your host's memory computer architecture is in little endian format, the `htons()` function becomes necessary but in case of big endian format memory architecture, it is not necessary.

You can find endianness of your computer programmatically too in the following way:

```
int x = 1;
if (*(char*)&x) {
    cout << "Little Endian\n";
} else {
    cout << "Big Endian\n";
}
```

And then decide whether to use `htons()` or not. But in order to avoid the above line, we always write `htons()` although it does no changes for big endian based memory architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the terms straight, `portno` is an *integer*, and `sockaddr` is a *streaming container*.

When you send data over the network you put them into a stream by a mechanism called *serialization*. In context of networking, the common rule is to put numbers in Big Endian byte order, i.e. higher value digits of an integtral type come first. If the memory layout of your processor architecture is Big Endian, too, the memory representation of an integer goes one by one to the container, else the byte order shall be adjusted. And this is what `htons` does: creating a short int value `sin_port`, such that it's memory layout meats the Big Endian representation of meant port number.