# Calculating checksum for ICMP echo request in Python

Tags: python-3.x, checksum, icmp

I am trying to implement a ping server in Python, and I am going through Pyping's source code as a reference: https://github.com/Akhavi/pyping/blob/master/pyping/core.py

I am not being able to understand the ***calculate_checksum*** function that has been implemented to calculate the checksum of the ICMP echo request. It has been am implemented as follows:

```
def calculate_checksum(source_string):

    countTo = (int(len(source_string) / 2)) * 2
    sum = 0
    count = 0

    # Handle bytes in pairs (decoding as short ints)
    loByte = 0
    hiByte = 0
    while count < countTo:
        if (sys.byteorder == "little"):
            loByte = source_string[count]
            hiByte = source_string[count + 1]
        else:
            loByte = source_string[count + 1]
            hiByte = source_string[count]
        sum = sum + (ord(hiByte) * 256 + ord(loByte))
        count += 2

    # Handle last byte if applicable (odd-number of bytes)
    # Endianness should be irrelevant in this case
    if countTo < len(source_string): # Check for odd length
        loByte = source_string[len(source_string) - 1]
        sum += ord(loByte)

    sum &= 0xffffffff # Truncate sum to 32 bits (a variance from ping.c, which
                      # uses signed ints, but overflow is unlikely in ping)

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff)  # Add high 16 bits to low 16 bits
    sum += (sum >> 16)                  # Add carry from above (if any)
    answer = ~sum & 0xffff              # Invert and truncate to 16 bits
    answer = socket.htons(answer)

    return answer
```

**sum &= 0xffffffff** is used for truncating the sum to 32 bits. However, what happens to the extra bit (the 33rd bit). Shouldn't that be added to the sum as a carry? Also, I am not being the able to understand the code after this.

I read the RFC1071 documentation (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1071.html) that explains how to implement the checksum, but I haven't been able to understand much.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure out the working of the **calculate_checksum** function, and I have tried to explain it below.

The checksum calculation is as follows (as per [RFC1071](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071)):

- Adjacent octets in the source_string are paired to form 16-bit
  integers, and the [1's complement sum](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/heasarc/ofwg/docs/general/checksum/node11.html) of these integers is
  calculated. *In case of odd number of octets, pairs are created out of the n-1 octets and added, and the remaining octet is added to the sum.*
- The resulting sum is truncated to 16-bits (carry bits are to be taken care of) and the checksum is calculated by taking it's 1's complement. The final checksum should be 16-bits long.

Let's take an example.

If the checksum is to be computed over the sequence of octets [A, B, C, D, E],  the pairs created would be [A, B] and [C, D], with the remaining octet E. The pairs [a, b] can be computed as follows:

> **a*256+b** where a and b are the octets

Say if a is 11001010 and b is 00010001, a*256+b = 1100101000010001 thus giving us the concatenated results of the octets.

The 1's complement sum is thus computed as follows:

> sum = [A+B] +' [C+D] +' E   where +' represents 1's complement
> addition

Now coming back to the code, everything before the line **sum &= 0xffffffff** calculates the 1's complement sum that we have calculated before.

---

**sum &= 0xffffffff**

is used for truncating the sum to 32-bits, although the sum exceeding is unlikely in ping as the size of the source_string is not very large

(source_string = header(8 bytes) + payload (variable length)).

---

**sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff)**

This piece of code is implemented for the case when the sum is greater than 16-bits. The sum is broken down into 2 parts:

(sum >> 16): the higher order 16-bits

(sum & 0xffff): the lower order 16-bits

and then these two parts are added. The final result can be 16-bits ogreater than 16-bits

---

**sum += (sum >> 16)**

This line is used in case the resulting sum from the previous computation is longer than 16-bits and is used to take care of the carry, similar to the previous line.

---

Finally, the 1's complement is calculated and truncated to 16 bits. The [socket.htons()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207745/htons-function-in-socket-programing) function is used for maintaining the arrangement of bytes sent to the network based on the architecture of your device (Little endian and big endian).